# Best way to implement calendar/event program in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I need a way of implementing a calendar for a webpage to show events this month for a local society i am a member of. I am looking at doing this project in RoR. But have no experience of calendars in RoR can any one recommend any good plugins for RoR for me to play with?
Thanks in Advance
Dean

Comment: This video help you http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars